# postgresql connection error while connecting with fastapi

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, asynchronous, fastapi, python-3.10

attempting postgres connection in fastapi getting this error

```
 conn = await _connect_addr(
  File "/home/joy/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 808, in _connect_addr
    return await __connect_addr(params, timeout, True, *args)
  File "/home/joy/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 860, in __connect_addr
    tr, pr = await compat.wait_for(connector, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/joy/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/compat.py", line 60, in wait_for
    return await asyncio.wait_for(fut, timeout)
  File "/home/joy/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 445, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "/home/joy/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 719, in _create_ssl_connection
    tr, pr = await loop.create_connection(
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1978, in create_connection
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

what to do to fix it, I crosschecked the values for all the values needed for connection still this error persists

Comment: It certainly looks like a DNS error.

Comment: "I crosschecked the values for all the values needed for connection"  How did you do that? Did you try plugging them into `psql`?  What did the command end up looking like, and what happened?